# Three-Finger UIPanGestureRecognizer doesn't work when Accessibility -> Zoom is on in "Settings App"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uiaccessibility

So, I have this code which basically creates a UIPanGestureRecognizer and adds it to the view. In the target method I am just printing the number of touches. It works fine under normal circumstance; and print correct number of touches.

But if "Settings -> Accessibility -> Zoom" is turned On, then it fails for 3-finger touch.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIPanGestureRecognizer *tempGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTempGesture:)];
  tempGesture.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
  tempGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 3;
  [tempGesture setDelegate:self];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tempGesture];
}

- (void)handleTempGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
  NSUInteger touches = recognizer.numberOfTouches;
  NSLog(@"Touches Count: %i", (int)touches);
}
```

Is there a way around it i.e. without having to turn off the zoom.

**PS:** Even 3-Finger UITapGestureRecognizer doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. However, you can alert users to the conflict and offer them the option to disable Accessibility Zoom using the [`UIAccessibilityRegisterGestureConflictWithZoom()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIAccessibilityRegisterGestureConflictWithZoom) API. Make sure to offer an alternative way to activate the feature so that users of zoom and other accessibility features can fully enjoy your application.